# SVN Switch is not deleting the folders / files in the working which is not present while switching to tag or branch

Tags: svn, switch-statement

I have a requirement to make a build based on the tag or branch. So I have automated my build process to do switch to a tag or branch whenever they are asking for the Builds. Iam using svn switch command to make the working copy point to tag or branch from trunk working copy. The problem is: If there are newly added folders present in the head revision, they are not getting deleted from the working copy. They  remain as unversioned in the working copy, but the unversioned folders in the build causing lot of problems. How to avoid this problem? Is there any option to avoid unversioned files while using svn switch command.

Answer (score 4):

there's no bug but you have to make sure that the workspace is really clean before switching. If it is clean, switching deletes/creates files and dirs that are present in only one version. To this end the subversion 1.6 manual says:

“Switching” a working copy that has no local modifications to a different branch results in the working copy looking just as it would if you'd done a fresh checkout of the directory.

I just tested this with a newly created test repository. If on the other hand there are local modifications in the current workspace, svn won't discard them. svn is pretty conservative with this respect. E.g. I created a directory `dir` on trunk and committed it. Then I created a backup file `dir/file.~1~`. It wasn't reported by `svn st` because `*~` is globally ignored with my config. When I switched back to a branch svn should have deleted `dir` but this would have deleted the backup file, so svn didn't do that. It kept the directory as a local modification.

side note: when switching forth to trunk again svn reported an error because `dir` as local modification on the branch was in conflict with the versioned `dir` on trunk. `--force` solved that problem.

Comment: You haven't read the problem well enough.  "svn add", and then "svn switch" to an old revision does cause unrevisioned files, but they should be deleted.  With a clean checkout, "svn switch" between different branches and tags should not cause conflicts - but indeed it does cause conflicts.  Maybe I should try to create a reproducable scenario ...

Comment: I tested now with a clean and empty repo, adding some files and directories gradually, and doing the tagging - but SVN did the right thing and deleted the newer files.  Weird.  I'm quite sure I did observe problems last week, and the problems was for sure not due to locally added files.  I will play a bit more with this.

Comment: Ok, I think maybe you're on to something here.  My research here is too long to fit into a comment, so I'll write a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

SVN switch wont delete unversioned files as you've found.

The way I handle it in my build process (Cruise Control) is to always delete the entire working folder after every build.  Then when your build process does a SVN get, it will be into an empty directory and there will be no conflicts.

BTW this is why you should use a separate build server - then you wont have uncommitted dev work interfering with the build.

Comment: I think u didnt get my questions. Head revision will be having the some folders or files committed to the repo, while switching back, those folders shuld be deleted from the working copy. after switching to a branch/tag, the working copy shuld be equal to newly switched branch or Tag

Comment: I think you missed what I meant.. If you delete all from the working directory before switching, then it doesn't matter what was there before, or what is currently committed to any other branch/tag.  You will only have the code for the branch you want to build.

Comment: after deleting, can i do svn switch, instead of that i can do svn checkout. as the working copy is empty?Then wats the whole point of having svn switch command. Correct me if iam wrong?

Comment: I was offline.. Yes you can just use svn checkout on the empty directory, I do.  Svn switch is still useful for developing when you need to work on different branches.

Comment: I did the similar way what you suggested me, delete was not happening, i was getting the error folders are getting used some process. so every time deleteing was not happeing properly. I checked this after stopping the IIS in that machine. Still i was not able to delete the SVN working copy. So can you suggest me what delete command you are using. How can we forcefully delete even though some process is using the folder?

Comment: While an empty checkout for sure will work out, it is a bit more costly, ref http://xkcd.com/303/ - and besides, the fact that "svn switch" won't delete files that have been deleted in the repository is definitively a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Things works like they should, at least in svn 1.6.11 and higher.  However, a build process is quite likely to leave behind unrevisioned files.  Those may be transparent on "svn status" due to SVNIGNORE settings.  This may cause troubles when one expects svn to remove the whole directory.

I did some testing - I set up a new and empty repository, made a trunk and tags directories there, added one and one file while tagging it.  (the code sections below does not include the output and errors thrown by SVN, you're encouraged to copy it into a terminal window and see if you can duplicate the behaviour).

```
mkdir /tmp/workdir/
cd /tmp/workdir
svnadmin create /tmp/foobar
svn checkout file:///tmp/foobar/
svn mkdir foobar/tags
svn mkdir foobar/trunk
cd foobar
svn commit -m "trunk and tags"
## NOTE: in svn 1.8 and higher, it's needed with a --ignore-ancestry option below
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/trunk
```

(and here we can already see that it's doing the right thing - deleting the tags and trunk subdirectories)

```
touch file1
svn add file1
svn commit -m "added file1"
svn cp -m "file1 in tag1" . file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag1
```

And then again ...

```
touch file2
svn add file2
svn commit -m "added file2"
svn cp -m "file2 in tag2" . file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag2
```

Let's explicitly delete file1 from tag3

```
svn rm file1 
svn commit -m "deleted file1"
svn cp -m "file1 removed from tag3" file:///tmp/foobar/trunk/ file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag3/
```

... and a new directory as well ...

```
svn mkdir dir1
touch dir1/file3
svn add dir1/file3
svn commit -m "added dir1/file3"
svn cp -m "dir1/file3 in tag4" file:///tmp/foobar/trunk file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag4/
```

... and let's delete it in tag5 ...

```
svn rm dir1
svn commit -m "removed dir1/file3"
svn cp -m "dir1/file3 removed in tag5" file:///tmp/foobar/trunk file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag5/
```

... and let's check how switching works ...

```
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag1
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag2
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag3
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag4
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag5
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag4
```

... no problems whatsoever.  But, say that I modified dir1/file3 with emacs - it would typically make a backup file:

```
touch dir1/file3~
```

This doesn't show up on "svn status" due to default SVNIGNORE settings ...

```
svn status
```

But it's sufficient to break things:

```
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag5
svn status
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag4
```

The first command indicates that dir1 is deleted, but due to the unrevisioned file the directory gets standing.

"svn revert" unfortunately doesn't remove unrevisioned files ...

```
svn revert -R .
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag5
svn status
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag4
```

"make clean" may and may not work, depending on the environment.  One could of course make a script to remove it, i.e. like this:

```
rm -rf $(svn status --no-ignore | grep -E '^\?' | awk ' { print $2 ; }')
svn switch file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag4
```

Please note that the command above may do Bad Things when encountering file names with spaces.

One may also avoid some error messages above by using "--force":

```
touch dir1/file3~
svn switch --force file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag5
svn switch --force file:///tmp/foobar/tags/tag4
```

Note that mydir1/file3~ never gets deleted, but that the last switch won't fail

Answer (score 1):

Two years later...

After some tinkering around and seeing your question (Sandy) the answer is, yes, a Switch should delete the directory. I was having the same issue and figured this one out.

To be clear, the issue as I understand it is that you add a directory/folder to your branch, then switch back to the Trunk. This added folder should be deleted when switching back.

I saw that Tortoise SVN was trying to delete the folder but without error and without actually deleting the folder. Turns out there was some kind of permissions issue. Once I manually deleted the folder while on the Trunk, switching back and forth produced the expected results; the folder is deleted.